# Adding the alter table sciprts and running on SSDT solution

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2005, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I have an existing SSDT solution and I want to add up the alter table scripts in the solutions and running on the SSDT solution such that the tables are updated according to the scripts?

Example: if I already have a table student with two columns sid and sname and I have a script which add up new column city to the table How can I do this such that table is updated?

Answer (score 3):

So in your live database you have changed it and you want the change to be in SSDT?

If this is the case, do a schema compare with the project as the destination and database as the source - you can choose what to update and it will update the project instead of the database.